# WPF - MenuItem highlighting has unwanted secondary highlight

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls, contextmenu, highlighting

I have a `ContextMenu` on a `Button` and when shown it display a list of menu items, which is fine. If I move the mouse over an item in the menu, it highlights, but I also get a secondary highlight when I hover over and around the text, see the pictures below.

[image: incorrect-image]

How do I remove this? I've tried all types of styles, triggers and various other templates to remove the highlighting, but can't seem to make any of the work or display correctly.

There is nothing special about my context menu button either, see wpf below.

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTreeItem.MetaTargets}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"
                          Command="{Binding Path=SelectedTreeItem.AddTargetCommandRelay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                 />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

Ideally I want it to look like this when highlighted, regardless of where the mouse is within the confines of the highlighted item, see pic below.

[image]

Comment: Try setting the windows theme to classic, this will help you confirm if this is coming from the "default" Aero style, or from your own styles.

Comment: I'm already using classic, and I'm not applying any of my own styling to the control at all.

Comment: I'm also running Windows 8

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late answer but maybe it could help someone.

The secondary highlight is there because you actually have an extra MenuItem inside the original one.

It is a bit counter-intuitive but when you bind ItemsSource of a menu in WPF, it automatically creates MenuItems without giving it a DataTemplate. The DataTemplate you're providing is actually going inside a ContentPresenter in the originally created MenuItem.

So you should be using ItemContainerStyle to style the MenuItem, rather than giving it a DataTemplate.

I don't have the opportunity to try the following code now, but it should fix the issue:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTreeItem.MetaTargets}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedTreeItem.AddTargetCommandRelay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `Property="IsHighlighted"` trigger from default MenuItem template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FFCDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFE6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="M0,5.1L1.7,5.2 3.4,7.1 8,0.4 9.2,0 3.3,10.8z" Fill="#FF0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#8071CBF1"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FFEEE9E9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FFDBD6D6"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following style for my ContextMenu instances. Obviously you can change the colors to suit.

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="LightBlue">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

If that doesn't work you could go down the route of restyling your MenuItem too. Here is an example:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" >
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter  Margin="6,3,6,3" 
                                   ContentSource="Header"
                                   RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <Popup Name="Popup"
                       Placement="Bottom"
                       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                       AllowsTransparency="True" 
                       Focusable="False"
                       PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border Name="SubmenuBorder"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="#FF2D2D30"
                            BorderBrush="#FF2D2D30"
                            BorderThickness="1" >
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" >
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" 
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Name="Icon"
                                  Margin="6,0,6,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  ContentSource="Icon"/>
                <Border Name="Check"  
                        Width="13" Height="13" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Margin="6,0,6,0" 
                        Background="#FF2D2D30"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#FF2D2D30">
                    <Path Name="CheckMark"
                          Width="7" Height="7" 
                          Visibility="Hidden" 
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                          Stroke="DodgerBlue"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="5,2,0,2"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsCheckable" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}"  TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Name="Icon"
                                  Margin="6,0,6,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  ContentSource="Icon"/>
                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="5,2,2,2"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <Path Grid.Column="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" 
                      Fill="DodgerBlue" />
                <Popup Name="Popup"
                       Placement="Right"
                       HorizontalOffset="-4" 
                       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                       AllowsTransparency="True" 
                       Focusable="False"
                       PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border Name="SubmenuBorder"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="#FF2D2D30"
                            BorderBrush="#FF2D2D30"
                            BorderThickness="1" >
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, your styling doesn't cover mouse over events, so I still see the secondary highlighting on mouse over.

Comment: However your second example is closer, give or take a little extra styling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with a custom MenuItem template containing just a Label:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ReportLayouts}" x:Name="CtxReportsMenu">
   <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <MenuItem Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.ReportCmd}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding }">
             <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                   <Label Content="{Binding Report_Description}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
             </MenuItem.Template>
           </MenuItem>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
```